# How to add the output from an app to the topbar

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-shell

Recently I installed the [Argos](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos) extension to add plugins to the topbar.
I managed to successfully install two or three things made by someone else, then I tried to do one on my own, basically what I wanted to do was add the output of this [application](https://github.com/Sapd/HeadsetControl) in the topbar.

I wrote a simple .sh file, added it to the Argos folder and it works. It tells me the battery percentage of my headphones, but it never updates and only shows the initial percentage.

[image: Output of the application in the terminal is different from the topbar]

I looked for how to fix it by looking in the [Argos documentation](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos#usage), renamed the .sh file, added ".3s" to the filename, so it would supposedly update every 3 seconds, but it still doesn't work.
I'm not really sure what the problem might be, I think it's my .sh file, since the other things in the topbar do work fine. 
***batteryLevel.r.3s.sh***

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

headsetcontrol -b
echo "Refresh... | refresh=true"
```

Anyone know how I can fix it?
I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04.2, thanks.

Comment: "Argos monitors the directory ~/.config/argos for changes. Any executable file found in this directory is considered a plugin. Files whose name starts with a dot (.) and files in subdirectories are ignored."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install gnome-shell-extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2932/executor/

and at command in the settings of the extension, you can give paht to your executable file.

[image]

[image]